# Handling multiple Try/Except statements

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I am using multiple try/except blocks to assign values of a dataframe (say data) to 3 variables(say b,c,d) I want to handle **IndexErrors** if positional indexer is out-of-bounds. What I am currently doing is shown below:

```
b,c,d=None,None,None
try:
    b=data.iloc[1,1]
except:
    pass
try:
    c=data.iloc[2,1]
except:
    pass
try:
    d=data.iloc[0,2]
except:
    pass
```

I want to know if there is a better of doing this like a function try_except() or something so that I can use it as shown below:

```
try_except(b=data.iloc[1,1])
try_except(c=data.iloc[2,1])
try_except(d=data.iloc[0,2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write a function that performs a lookup and catches the exception, but incidentally, `except: pass` is probably a bad idea. You should be more specific with your error handling.

```
def safe_get(container, i, j):
    try:
        return container[i,j]
    except IndexError: # or whatever specific error you're dealing with
        return None

b = safe_get(data.iloc, 1, 1)
c = safe_get(data.iloc, 2, 1)
d = safe_get(data.iloc, 0, 2)
```